# Unit of work sql query performance degraded

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work

I'm having a performance problem when using Unit of Work to do queries.

When I'm using DbContext directly I make a linq query something like this:

`var result = from x in ctx.client
               select new { Name= x.name };`

When I'm using Unit I make the following code:

`var result = from x in uow.GetClientRepository.GetAll()
               select new { Name = x.name };`

What generates a SQL query type:

`Select * from Client`

The above code would generate a SQL query of type:

`Select name from Client`

Comment: Please share code of `GetClientRepository.GetAll()` method

Comment: Make GetAll() return IQueryable<T>, and avoid running the query inside GetAll().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on David's answer:

If GetAll() is returning `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` or the like and looks something like:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
   return _context.TEntities.ToList();
}
```

Then you will want to change this to something along the lines of:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
   return _context.TEntities.AsQueryable();
}
```

Further to this in case someone comes across this and wonders why to use it; The pattern can be beneficial to centralize core business rules for the application such as Soft-Delete active state:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
   return _context.TEntities
      .Where(x => x.IsActive);
}
// Note: AsQueryable() is not needed when the method returns IQueryable<T>
```

or enforcing authorization such as tenancy... (multiple clients accessing a single cloud service where their data is expected to be isolated.)

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
   var tenantId = UserLocatorService.GetCurrentUserTenantId();
   return _context.TEntities
      .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.TopLevelEntity.TenantId == tenantId);
}
```

where UserLocatorService represents a dependency service to assess the current logged in user and which tenant they represent.